# LTRfootnote doesn't have correct order

Tags: footnotes, texmaker

The `LTRfootnote` of my first page doesn't have order.

The minimalExample:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[Kashida]{xepersian}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\zmakeperpage{footnote}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.4cm}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8.5pt}{0}\selectfont} 
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fontsize{6.5pt}{0}\selectfont\arabic{footnote}}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.2cm}

\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\settextfont[Scale=1.2, ItalicFont=*, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.32}, BoldItalicFont=* Bold, BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.32}]{B Nazanin}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\fontsize{15pt}{0}\selectfont  \flushleft  \bfseries \BNazaninScaleOne} % B Nazanin 15
{\chaptertitlename\ \tartibi{chapter}}{0.3cm}{\fontsize{15pt}{0}\selectfont \BNazaninScaleOne} % B Nazanin 15


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
هدف مهندسی مدل‌رانده%
\LTRfootnote{Model-Driven Engineering}

هدف مهندسی مدل‌رانده%
\LTRfootnote{Model-Driven Engineering}
هدف مهندسی مدل‌رانده%
\LTRfootnote{Model-Driven Engineering}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output:]

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which demonstrates the problem

Comment: Thanks for more information. But you have not really provided a **minimal** working example. It needs to start with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}` and be compilable. You are asking us to debug your 750 line style file... What's more, when I compile a simple example using your style and the `book` class I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DavidPurton I edited my question. would you please help me?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you want. Your example now compiles fine for me and I get the output I would expect. What do you mean by "The `LTRfootnote` on my first page doesn't have order?" You example gives three footnotes numbered 1 to 3 for me.

Comment: @DavidPurton It generates 1,2,1 for me.

Comment: You have a lot of unneeded packages loaded in your MWE. Try and remove as many as you can.

Comment: @DavidPurton different runs causes different results.

Comment: still runs fine for me, no matter how many times I run it. Simplify your MWE as much as you can (remove non-essential packages) and add `\listfiles` at the top of the document, then post the version numbers of files reported.